# Python CSV transpose data in one column to rows

Tags: python, csv, matrix, transpose

I have a CSV file containing data only in the first column,

[image]

I want to **use python to transpose every 4 rows to another empty CSV file**, for example, row 1 to row 4 transposed to the first row; then row 5 to row 8 transposed to the second row,...etc, and finally we can get a 5 * 4 matrix in the CSV file.

[image]

How to write a script to do this？ Please give me any hint and suggestion, thank you.

I am using python 2.7.4 under Windows 8.1 x64.

---

**update#1**

I use the following code provided by thefortheye,

```
import sys, os
os.chdir('C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop')
print os.getcwd()

from itertools import islice
with open("test_csv.csv") as in_f, open("Output.csv", "w") as out_file:
    for line in ([i.rstrip()] + map(str.rstrip, islice(in_f, 3)) for i in in_f):
        out_file.write("\t".join(line) + "\n")
```

the input CSV file is,

[image]

and the result is,

[image]

This is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use List comprehension like this

```
data = range(20)
print data
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
print[data[i:i + 4] for i in xrange(0, len(data), 4)]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18,19]]
```

Instead of `4`, you might want to use `56`.

Since you are planing to read from the file, you might want to do something like this

```
from itertools import islice
with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
    print [[int(line)] + map(int, islice(in_file, 3)) for line in in_file]
```

**Edit** As per the updated question,

```
from itertools import islice
with open("Input.txt") as in_f, open("Output.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for line in ([i.rstrip()] + map(str.rstrip, islice(in_f, 3)) for i in in_f):
        out_file.write("\t".join(line) + "\n")
```

**Edit:** Since you are looking for comma separated values, you can join the lines with `,`, like this

```
        out_file.write(",".join(line) + "\n")
```

Comment: Could I just transpose data and get a resulting matrix-form data contained in the CSV file?

Comment: @Heinz What is your expected output?

Comment: @Heinz Can you please reduce the data to a small dataset and produce the expected output?

Comment: @Heinz I think you need `out_file.write(",".join(line) + "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use List comprehension and double-loop like this.

```
>>> M = 3
>>> N = 5
>>> a = range(M * N)
>>> o = [[a[i * N + j] for j in xrange(N)] for i in xrange(M)]
>>> print o
[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
 [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```